# Solving the integral $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{1-e^{z}}dz$ with the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $\gamma:[0,2 \pi] \to \mathbb{C};\; \gamma(t):= e^{it} \;$ be the boundary curve of the unit circle. How to solve the integral $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{1-e^{z}}dz$ with the residue theorem?
Since the function $z \to \frac{1}{1-e^{z}}$ only has an isolated singularity at $z=0$ we get $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{1-e^{z}}dz= 2\pi i \; Res_{0}(f)$. The residue of f at $0$ should be calculated via the Laurentcoefficient or? But I don't know what the Laurentexpansion looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0$ is a pole of order $1$ and the residue is given by $\lim_{z \to 0} z \frac 1 {1-e^{z}}$ which is $-1$ by L'Hopital's Rule.

In general if $f$ has a pole of order $1$ at $z_0$ then the residue at $z_o$ is $\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)f(z)$. [The order of the pole is necessarily $1$ if this limit exists].